# How to merge lines previously broken by black due to violating the line length constraint when removing a few arguments?

Tags: python-black

Assume I have a single-line function call that exceeds black's line length constraint. Black will reformat this function call to a multi-line function call to satisfy the constraint, e.g.,

```py
replace_config(user_args, tune_args, container_type, class_name, param_names)
```

```py
replace_config(
    user_args,
    tune_args,
    container_type,
    class_name,
    param_names,
)
```

Further assume I would like to remove the last three arguments, which are optional, from this function call. My new code would look like this:

```py
replace_config(
    user_args,
    tune_args,
)
```

How can I tell black to shorten this multi-line function call to a single-line function call because it no longer violates the line length constraint?

The output should look like this:

```py
replace_config(user_args, tune_args)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into the [magic trailing comma feature](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/the_black_code_style/current_style.html#the-magic-trailing-comma). Black will never collapse any collections or function argument/parameter lists if it has a trailing comma.

You can either disable the magic trailing comma feature by passing `-C` or `--skip-magic-trailing-comma`, or simply just remove the trailing comma (and the next time Black formats the file, it'll happily collapse the function call as you'd expect).

[FWIW there's an open issue on the issue tracker about this](https://github.com/psf/black/issues/2135).